# RegEx for URL pattern(s), redirect after re-launch

Tags: php, regex, url, regex-lookarounds

I have been struggling and testing for the last two hours and simply cannot wrap my head around the whole RegEx-stuff enough in order to find a proper solution to this...

I am trying to redirect a couple of URLs from our old site to the new one due to a recent re-launch.

[This is the current state of things / a demo of my RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/HsIDkQ/3/)

Essentially it looks like this:

```
.+(\/es|\/de|\/en)?\/(legal)(.+)?
```

My problem is that a URL like `https://example.com/es/projects/legal-yeah` is also being matched, which does make sense looking at the rule but is not what I want to achieve...

How can I perform a test which **only matches URLs where there is nothing in between** the first part for the language string (de/en/es/empty) and the second part (/legal)?

Thanks so much for sharing your thoughts on this, appreciate it!

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/HsIDkQ/4 - Not sure if I understood your question correctly - can you tell us exactly what example strings in the regex101 test should match?

Comment: Oh now I got what you mean by `empty` - not the string but actually empty :p

Comment: Are you dealing with RewriteRules in .htaccess?

Comment: Hey @revo – was initially trying to create a nginx-ruleset but should be htaccess-based now

Comment: Might you have a URL like `https://example.com/lang/es/legal-yeah`? Should it match?

Comment: There will either be the language-string or nothing prepended, no /lang/ or similar before that. I found a way: https://regex101.com/r/HsIDkQ/14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This final RegEx-rule matches the URLs like I intended – ignoring any other occurences of the "legal"-string (in this case) which *might* appear in another URL on some other level and 'fuzzy' enough to include all the language-cases, even without a language-string appearing at all.

[Solution](https://regex101.com/r/HsIDkQ/18)

<s>The trick in the end was to force the rule to look for a TLD in front of the other stuff so it would only allow for first-level URLs to be included.</s>

**UPDATE:** My first solution didn't turn out to work since the redirection engine / plugin only makes use of the URL path, not including the domain ([see GitHub issue](https://github.com/johngodley/redirection/issues/523)) and as such I can't match the DOT as needed precessor.

Now the rule is paying attention to the start of the string and not accepting anything other the language string in front of the targeted URL-slug which in turn removes false positives.

Thanks to @Xatenev who pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

By using an end-of-line anchor `$` and explicitly adding `(\/.*)` after legal you can achieve what you need:

```
.+(\/es|\/de|\/en)?\/(legal)(\/.+)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/HsIDkQ/8

Comment: Hey @Xatenev,

nice one but unfortunately doesn't cover all the cases yet – I've updated the example (https://regex101.com/r/HsIDkQ/9) to include a URL like https://example.com/es/projects/legal which still gets matched although there is /projects/ in between...

Comment: I see your point(s) but it needs to be acessing the full URL (12) and should work without including the base URL (13)...